# How to append "HTML tags" before and after each dropdown list item in Yii2 Active Form

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a list of Different colours. I have successfully created a dropdown list showing each colour name. But now my client wants to show the colour badges in front of each colour name. I have colour codes stored too in my database but is there any way I can show the colour badges in front of colour names.

1. I also tried ArrayHelper::map function like below

   $colours_list_array = ArrayHelper::map($colours_list, 'id', 'colour_name');

But the above is showing me the error.

2. I also tried writing the direct html to my colour names in the database but now in the dropdown, it is showing me the exact same html tag as a String.

[image]

**Can anyone please tell me how can I show the colour badges in front of the list item??**

->> Below is my database table of colours

[image]

->> Here is my ActiveForm Input of Colours Dropdown

```
<?= $form->field($colours_model, 'colour_name')->dropDownList(
        $colours_model->getColours(),
) ?>
```

Comment: `$colours_model->getColours()` returns all the values including all column values?

Comment: No. It returns the value in array format like this. Array(['id'=>'colour_name']);

Comment: You tried the answer which is provided below?

Answer (score 0):

Change function name as per your code

```
$colors = $colours_model->getColours(); //Assuming this function retrieving all records
$arrayColour = $arrayColorList = [];
foreach($colours as $colour){
    $colour_id = $colour->getId(); //get 'id' column data
    $colour_name = $colour->getColourName(); //Get 'colour_name' column data
    $colour_code = $colour->getColourCode(); //Get 'colour_code' column data

    $arrayColorList[$colour_id] = $colour_name;
    $arrayColour[$colour_id] = ["style" => "background-color:$colour_code"];
}

$form->field($colours_model, 'colour_name')->dropDownList($arrayColorList, ['prompt' => 'Please select', 'options' => $arrayColour])->label(false);
```

**Output:**

```
<select>
    <option value='3' style="background-color:#FFFFF">White</option>
    <option value='4' style="background-color:#C0C0C0"><b>SILVER</b></option>
    .
    .
    .
</select>
```

Inspect this dropdown and check whether "style" attribute is appending in each option list or not. Then, test it in Chrome browser first. Mozilla having some problem related to this.

I had similar requirement in one of the project and with same code it's working fine for me.